# How to multiply a slice of a sparse scipy matrix by a constant without changing sparsity

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, multiplication

Whenever I multiply a slice of a sparse matrix by a constant in place, I lose the sparsity of the matrix because Scipy starts to compute `0 * constant` for every empty entry and then fills all empty entries with `0`. This is stupid. How do I stop it from doing that? Indexes need to be integers or booleans. They cannot use `:`.

So for example

```
A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[0, 1], [0, 0]])
print(A, '/n' )

A[[0,0],[0,1]] *= -1
print(A)
```

results in

```
(0, 1)  1 

(0, 0)  0
(0, 1)  -1
```

The size of A should not have changed.

EDIT:
Since it seems to be unclear what I am trying to achieve, I want to multiply a number of elements from a sparse matrix by a constant without losing the sparsity of that matrix and without having to resort to operations that are more expensive than linear in the number non zero elements in that number of elements i.e. using the sparse structure. So also no copying the entire sparse matrix which means the multiplication has to be in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
A[0, 1] *= -1
```

Then

```
print(A)
```

yields

```
(0, 1)  -1
```

or, in this case at least, simply

```
print(A * (-1))
```

yielding the same output:

```
(0, 1)  -1
```

By doing

```
A[[0,0],[0,1]]
```

you select zero-entries which are then filled; if you select only the one non-zero entry as shown above it works as expected.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
A = csr_matrix([[0, 1], [5, 0]])
```

Now you can simply do

```
print(A * (-1))
(0, 1)  -1
(1, 0)  -5
```

You can also modify specific entries by passing tuples

```
A[(0, 1), (1, 0)] *= -1
print(A)
```

will also return the desired output:

```
(0, 1)  -1
(1, 0)  -5
```

Clearly, if you want to change all non-zero entries, I would just go with

```
A * (-1)
```

Comment: This was my first thought but the loop required for this requires me to call the indices of the rows for all rows that are in the spice which then dominates the runtime of the entire algorithm by a couple orders of magnitude.

Comment: It all comes down to scipy sparse not returning a sparse matrix when you slice a sparse matrix

Comment: @student: Just pass a tuple of the desired indices then; see my edit. Is that what you need? If you want to change all nonzero entries, just use `A * (-1)` as shown above, if several specific entries, pass the `tuple`.

Comment: But that does not work if you use `A[(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)] *= -1` imagine you have `10000x100000` matrix and you need to find the non zero entries efficient in a random tuple. How would I do that in linear time (in the number of non zero entries in the slice)?

Comment: @student: Of course, this setting gives issues as you then change the dimensions of your original matrix. What do you mean by "random tuple"? If you want to get the nonzero entries just use `A.nonzero()`.

Comment: A.nonzero() isn't an in place operation. Since this question is about sparse matrices, any answer that requires `n^2` operations isn't an answer at all.

Comment: @student. I guess then you will have to explain what's wrong `A * (-1)` and to edit your question as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve (at least to me).

Comment: Just pull out data, indices, indptr then multiply data*constant.